# Solution for collecting payments from Ionic Mobile app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, payment-gateway, hybrid-mobile-app, paytm

I have developed a website which can accept online payment through PayTm (A payment gateway in India). I post the cust_id and amount to a file in my server (say redirect.php) which in turn generates other required parameters including checksumhash and redirect the user to payment gateway to complete the payment. This works fine

Now, I am developing a hybrid mobile app using ionic framework and wanting to collect payment using PayTm. I tried finding a plugin but couldn't.

So here is the solution i am planning to implement, please let me know if it is a good idea or do you have any better one.

- create a form in mobile app and generate a random order_id
- Accept the amount from the user in the form and submit
- Using form post method, post the data to redirect.php and redirect the user to redirect.php (The file stored in my server). This will open in a new browser window.
- The app keeps querying the db for the status of the order_id
- meanwhile, user completes the transaction in the gateway and the window is closed.
- User returns back to app and the app displays the status of the transaction.

Comment: Have u used the same method or any other thing? Plz tell me if you have a working solution.

Comment: Ya i have implemented the same and it works fine so far... At present my app has very few users and so far did not find any issue. Will post if i come across any.

Comment: bro can u post a sample app for me it will be very helpful. I am struggling to make it work on Ionic.